# R Extract a word from a character string using pattern matching

Tags: r, regex, pattern-matching

I need some help with pattern matching in R. I need to extract a whole word that starts with a common prefix, from a long character string. The word I want to extract always starts with the same prefix (AA), but the word is not the same length, and does not occur in the same location of the string.

```
mytext1 <- as.character("HORSE MONKEY LIZARD AA12345 SWORDFISH") # Return AA12345

mytext2 <- as.character("ELEPHANT AA100 KOALA POLAR.BEAR") # Want to return AA100

mytext3 <- as.character("CROCODILE DRAGON.FLY ANTELOPE") # Want to return NA
```

As an extension of this, what if there were two different patterns to match and I wanted to return a character string with both?

```
mytext4 <- as.character("TULIP AA999 DAISY BB123") 
# Pattern matching to AA and BB 
# Want to return AA999 BB123
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a `stringr` approach. The regular expression matches `AA` preceded by a space or the start of the string `(?<=^| )`, and then as few characters as possible `.*?` until the next space or the end of the string `(?=$| )`. Note that you can combine all the strings into a vector and a vector will be returned. If you want all matches for each string, then use `str_extract_all` instead of `str_extract` and you get a list with a vector for each string. If you want to specify multiple matches, use an option and a capturing group `(AA|BB)` as shown.

```r
mytext <- c(
  as.character("HORSE MONKEY LIZARD AA12345 SWORDFISH"), # Return AA12345
  as.character("ELEPHANT AA100 KOALA POLAR.BEAR"), # Want to return AA100,
  as.character("AA3273 ELEPHANT KOALA POLAR.BEAR"), # Want to return AA3273
  as.character("ELEPHANT KOALA POLAR.BEAR AA5785"), # Want to return AA5785
  as.character("ELEPHANT KOALA POLAR.BEAR"), # Want to return nothing
  as.character("ELEPHANT AA12345 KOALA POLAR.BEAR AA5785") # Can return only AA12345 or both
)

library(stringr)
mytext %>% str_extract("(?<=^| )AA.*?(?=$| )")
#> [1] "AA12345" "AA100"   "AA3273"  "AA5785"  NA        "AA12345"
mytext %>% str_extract_all("(?<=^| )AA.*?(?=$| )")
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "AA12345"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "AA100"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "AA3273"
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] "AA5785"
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> character(0)
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> [1] "AA12345" "AA5785"

as.character("TULIP AA999 DAISY BB123") %>% str_extract_all("(?<=^| )(AA|BB).*?(?=$| )")
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "AA999" "BB123"
```

Created on 2018-04-29 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: This often works, however fails when the word is at the end of the character string, for example, wrongly returns NA if the string is `mytext2 <- as.character("ELEPHANT KOALA POLAR.BEAR AA100")`

Comment: Adapted to new cases not mentioned in original question. I additionally suggest that you read through a guide to regular expressions and understand what the string is doing, because that will make it significantly easier to understand the process and make it easy to make adjustments instead of taking others' code as a black box. This is a good `stringr` resource http://r4ds.had.co.nz/strings.html

Comment: Thanks, I had done quite a bit of research into stringr, and found the cheat sheet (https://www.rstudio.com/resources/cheatsheets/) to have a lot of answers, but was not overly familiar with regex syntax, especially for complex searches. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a base R solution using `sub`

```
sub(".*\\b(AA\\w*).*", "\\1", mytext1)
[1] "AA12345"
> sub(".*\\b(AA\\w*).*", "\\1", mytext2)
[1] "AA100"
```

Comment: Thanks, this works as long as the character string contains the pattern in it, but returns the whole string if the pattern is not present, for example:
 

`mytext3 <- as.character("CROCODILE DRAGON.FLY ANTELOPE")
sub(".*\\b(AA\\w*).*", "\\1", mytext3)
[1] "CROCODILE DRAGON.FLY ANTELOPE"
# would like to return NA`

Answer (score 1):

I like keeping things in base R whenever possible, and there is already a solution for this. What you really are looking for is the `regmatches()` function. [See Here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regmatches.html)

> Extract or replace matched substrings from match data obtained by regexpr, gregexpr or regexec.

To solve your specific problem

```
matches = regexpr("(?<=^| )AA.*?(?=$| )", mytext1, perl=T)
regmatches(mytext1, matches)
> [1] "AA12345"
```

When there is no match:

```
matches = regexpr("(?<=^| )AA.*?(?=$| )", mytext3, perl=T)
regmatches(mytext3, matches)
> character(0)
```

If you want to avoid `character(0)` put your strings in a vector and run them all at once.

```
alltext = c(mytext1, mytext2, mytext3)
matches = regexpr("(?<=^| )AA.*?(?=$| )", alltext, perl=T)
regmatches(alltext, matches)
> [1] "AA12345" "AA100"
```

And finally, if you want a one-liner

```
regmatches(alltext, regexpr("(?<=^| )AA.*?(?=$| )", alltext, perl=T))
> [1] "AA12345" "AA100"
```